# Power BI Embedded PostImportWithFile returning BadRequest

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm looking to post a PBIX file up to a workspace through the .NET API using the PostImportWithFile method of the PowerBiClients Imports object. The code is pretty much identical to that seen in option 6 of the Provision Sample (see https://github.com/Azure-Samples/power-bi-embedded-integrate-report-into-web-app/blob/master/ProvisionSample/Program.cs).

There is a workspace collection and a workspace that have been created. The workspace was created through code using the relevant API methods so I know that the authentication side of things is working correctly.

When I call the PostImportWithFile method I'm getting a BadRequest exception being thrown. To verify that this wasn't something to do with my code I've compiled and run the ProvisionSample and selected option 6 and selected the same file and received the same result.

I'm supplying null for the dataset parameter, which is optional and defaults to null anyway, so I can't see this being the cause of my issues.

I've been unable to find anything online regarding this method and a BadRequest so was wondering if there was anyone with experience with this API that had run into something similar?

The PBIX file works fine through Power BI Services, so I'm assuming nothing is wrong with the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powerbi.api.beta.importsextensions.postimportwithfileasync.aspx) it looks like you would need to supply a datasetname, it does not look like it is optional.

```
public static Task<Import> PostImportWithFileAsync(
this IImports operations,
string collectionName,
string workspaceId,
Stream fileStream,
string datasetDisplayName,
Nullable<int> nameConflict = null,
CancellationToken cancellationToken = null)
```

Non async version [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powerbi.api.beta.importsextensions.postimportwithfile.aspx) also looks like datasetdisplayname is not optional.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are correct, Import requires the datasetDisplayName to be set.

Comment: Hmm, the extension method is defined as public static Import PostImportWithFile(this IImports operations, string collectionName, string workspaceId, Stream fileStream, string datasetDisplayName = null, string nameConflict = null);

Comment: Hmm, the extension method is defined as public static Import PostImportWithFile(this IImports operations, string collectionName, string workspaceId, Stream fileStream, string datasetDisplayName = null, string nameConflict = null); which led me to think the datasetDisplayName was optional. I've just changed the code to supply a datasetDisplayName and things appeared to go through fine (no exception raised anyway), however the Import object that was returned had null for everything bar the Id property (so the reports collection wasn't populated etc). A step forwards anyway, thanks for the help.